# What is the IOS (Cisco) command line is all about?

Tags: command-line, router

1) what are the devices that I can use the IOS command line with them ?? are there any home device or all are for company??

2) can I use the IOS command line with the linksys router (E1000 or E2000) ??

3) when is learning to use the IOS command line is essential with the cisco routers ?? can't i just do all my job with the GUI ??

I'm asking about IOS command line since i'm willing to learn the CCNA , and there are topics about it. so, i want to know a brief description about it...

Thanks alot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cisco's IOS is used on Cisco's hardware, such as routers, switches, security devices, etc.  Although Cisco also puts its name on consumer level devices, they do not run Cisco IOS.  They are generally configured through a web-based GUI.
2. Nope.  Those are both consumer devices.
3. Some of the enterprise class hardware does allow access via a web-based GUI, however, as arved mentioned, the command line allows you to move about more quickly, and once you are familiar with IOS, it is indeed faster and more efficient.

Good luck with the CCNA!

Answer (score 2):

2) No.

Answering 3) With the commandline you are much faster as you can copyNpaste or better script the changes you are intending to do.

If you are looking for training expertise, there are emulators out there.